# How can I fix this so the h:graphicImage is aligned to the right?

Tags: html, css, jsf

Right now I have the following but it is not moving the image to the right. I want to have the header and a tiny image inside the facet where the image is at the far right. The only part not working for me is the right alignment. Any suggestions?

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:panelGroup id="headerwrapper" >
        <h:outputText id="header"
                      styleClass="outputText"
                      value="TableTitle"
                      style="font-weight:bold;"/>

        <h:graphicImage id="img1"
                        value=img.gif"
                        height="13"
                        width="13"
                        style="horizontal-align:right;"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css `float:right;`.

```
<h:graphicImage id="img1"
    library="images/icons"
    name="ic_new.png"
    style="float:right;"/>
```